# How do I list available casts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, cast

In PostgreSQL, there is a command, `\dC+` I can use in psql `\dC+`,

```
\dC[+]  [PATTERN]      list casts
```

To lists the possible `CASTS`. This is useful, because I can easily find out *what* I can use to cast to `timestamp`,

```
\dC+ timestamp
                                             List of casts
         Source type         |         Target type         |  Function   |   Implicit?   | Description 
-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------------+-------------
 abstime                     | timestamp without time zone | timestamp   | yes           | 
 date                        | timestamp without time zone | timestamp   | yes           | 
 timestamp without time zone | abstime                     | abstime     | in assignment | 
 timestamp without time zone | date                        | date        | in assignment | 
 timestamp without time zone | timestamp without time zone | timestamp   | yes           | 
 timestamp without time zone | timestamp with time zone    | timestamptz | yes           | 
 timestamp without time zone | time without time zone      | time        | in assignment | 
 timestamp with time zone    | timestamp without time zone | timestamp   | in assignment |
```

Is there any command like that in SQL Server? How can I find what I *can* `CAST` to `DateTime2`? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Microsoft Docs page for CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-conversions) provides a great matrix of conversions in SQL Server.

The image included in the above page:

[image]

As far as I know, there is no built-in mechanism for displaying a list of valid casts.